# My JS function doesnt work on planning.role in Odoo 16

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo, odoo-16

I'm working on customizing filters in an Odoo dashboard with the ks_dashboard_ninja module. The code defines various filter append functions (like appendRoleFilter, appendProjectFilter, etc.), which add specific filters to the dashboard based on conditions. Can anyone help me identify why this function "appendRoleFilter" might not be working as intended?

This is an exemple of my function appendProjectFilter which works perfectly :

```
appendProjectFilter: function () {
            var self = this;
            this._rpc({
                model: 'project.project',
                method: 'search_read',
                args: [[['active', '=', true], ['stage_id', 'in', [2, 3]]]],
            }).then(function (projects) {
                self.$('.my_project').append('<select class="btn-fill-primary" id="project_selector"></select>');
                projects.forEach(function (project) {
                    self.$('#project_selector').append('<option value="' + project.id + '">' + project.name + '</option>');
                });
                self.$('#project_selector').change(function () {
                    var selected_project_id = $(this).val();
                    self._rpc({
                        model: 'ks_dashboard_ninja.board_custom_filters',
                        method: 'write',
                        args: [[self.ks_dashboard_board_id], {
                            'project_id': parseInt(selected_project_id)
                        }],
                    }).then(function () {
                        Object.keys(self.ks_dashboard_data.ks_item_data).forEach(function (item_id) {
                            var models = self.ks_dashboard_data.ks_item_model_relation[item_id];
                            var my_custom_domain;
                            if (models.includes("project.project")) {
                                my_custom_domain = [['id', '=', parseInt(selected_project_id)]];
                            } else {
                                my_custom_domain = [['project_id', '=', parseInt(selected_project_id)]];
                            }
                            if (my_custom_domain) {
                                self.ksFetchUpdateItemCustom(item_id, my_custom_domain);
                            }
                        });
                    })
                });
            });
        },
```

And here is the appendRoleFilter function which does not display anything, neither the 'select', nor the 'options' :

```
appendRoleFilter: function () {
            var self = this;
            this._rpc({
                model: 'planning.role',
                method: 'search_read',
            }).then(function (roles) {
                self.$('.role_pure').append('<select class="btn-fill-primary" id="role_selector"></select>');
                roles.forEach(function (role) {
                    self.$('#role_selector').append('<option value="' + role.id + '">' + role.name + '</option>');
                });
                self.$('#role_selector').change(function () {
                    var selected_role_id = $(this).val();
                    self._rpc({
                        model: 'ks_dashboard_ninja.board_custom_filters',
                        method: 'write',
                        args: [[self.ks_dashboard_board_id], {
                            'role_id': parseInt(selected_role_id)
                        }],
                    })
                })
            });
        },
```

Here is also the DOM I override :

```
<templates>
    <t t-inherit="ks_dashboard_ninja.ksDashboardNinjaHeader" t-inherit-mode="extension" t-name="ksDashBoardNinjaHeaderExtend">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('ks_dashboard_header')]" position="inside">
            <div class="role_pure"/>
            <div class="my_employee"/>
            <div class="my_project"/>
            <div class="my_partner"/>
        </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>
```